# Rotating View Matrix produces flat shapes

Tags: android, opengl-es, view, matrix

I'm trying to rotate my view matrix in opengl es 2 on Android. I simply do

`Matrix.rotateM(mVM, 0, .1f, .5f, .5f, 0);`

on the drawing of the frame. However, when I do this, I see the camera rotating as wanted, but the 3d shapes do not rotate. These shapes are created facing the camera, and as the camera rotates you see the same face and not the sides. The shapes are skewed as they should be as the camera rotates around them. If I call

```
Matrix.rotateM(MM, 0, 1, .5f, .1f, 0);
```

in each individual shape's rendering, it works fine and I can see all sides of the shape. But I want to move the camera about the origin (which is working) and see the shapes in a 3d manner (which is not working)

Comment: There's not enough information: what other matrices do you have? How do you multiply them? (or do you?)

Comment: I solved my problem, it was not related to matrices. I have a small framework I made for handling opengl and in my main Shape class to save memory I used only 2 dimensions and now I require 3 and just have to fix it. Thank you anyways.